# Bootstrap 5.3 Create basic color-mode

Tags: symfony, webpack, sass, bootstrap-5, webpack-encore

I would like to know how to create a simple new color-mode for Bootstrap 5.3. **All I want to do is replace**

`$primary: $blue;`

with

`$primary: #1e407c;`

I want to replace all the usages of `$primary` with this new color.

I am using webpack to build the sass for my site's custom css files.

I have read the [documentation about color modes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/color-modes/) but am confused because they seem to show two different methods

1. [using color-mode(name)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/color-modes/#how-it-works)
2. [using data-bs-theme="name"](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/color-modes/#custom-color-modes)

I want to do this as a color-mode, not a simple override of the main primary color. In the end I will create multiple modes with different primary colors.

Which do I use and how do I use it? Where do I define my new color-mode? I use Symfony with webpack and webpack-encore. Here is how I currently import my **working** bootstrap files (basically [Option B](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/sass/#importing))

`assets/styles/app.scss:`

```
@import './components/bootstrap_custom';
// ...
```

`assets/styles/components/_bootstrap_custom.scss`

```
// 1. Include functions first (so you can manipulate colors, SVGs, calc, etc)
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";

// 2. Include any default variable overrides here
$body-bg:         #d9e0e7;
$link-decoration: none;

// 3. Include remainder of required Bootstrap stylesheets
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables-dark";

// 4. Include any default map overrides here
$link-color          : darken($primary, 15%);
$link-hover-color    : darken($link-color, 15%);
$input-bg            : tint-color($green, 95%);
$form-check-input-bg : $input-bg;
$form-select-bg      : $input-bg;
$breadcrumb-active-color: darken($primary, 30%);
// bs5.3 changed default bg colors for several elements to the $body-bg. Override back to white.
$card-bg             : $white;
$table-bg            : $white;
$dropdown-bg         : $white;
$list-group-bg       : $white;
//$enable-dark-mode    : false;

// 5. Include remainder of required parts
@import "~bootstrap/scss/maps";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/root";

// 6. Optionally include any other parts as needed
@import "~bootstrap/scss/utilities";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/containers";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/grid";

// currently including ALL parts
@import "~bootstrap/scss/tables";
// ... truncated for brevity
@import "~bootstrap/scss/placeholders";

@import "~bootstrap/scss/helpers";

// 7. Optionally include utilities API last to generate classes based on the Sass map in `_utilities.scss`
@import "~bootstrap/scss/utilities/api";

// 8. Add additional custom code here
```

Of course, this is all built by webpack and placed in `/public/build`

Comment: You keep referencing "Option B" but the doc says nothing about two different ways but instead "color mode styles are controlled by the `data-bs-theme` attribute"

Comment: I started to play around with this just after it was released, and quickly realized it's a major amount of work to get it working, good luck. It comes with dark-mode so you can use it as a guide but I'm pretty sure you have to duplicate everything that involves that mode.

Comment: @ArleighHix thank you for responding. "Option B" is shown in the code examples just under the **[Importing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/sass/#importing)** heading - the second code sample is labeled as "Option B". 

As for the two ways to create color modes, I linked both in 1 & 2 above. One is `data-bs-theme` the other uses `color-mode(name)` (a mixin I guess?).

I appreciate your response. perhaps this info will help you help me. I still haven't got anything to work.

Comment: @ArleighHix I was hoping you would have some new ideas today 

Answer (score 0):

You would just add the customizations as:

```
/* custom.scss */
@import "functions";
@import "variables";


[data-bs-theme="custommode"] {

    $primary: #1e407c; 
    $theme-colors: map-merge($theme-colors, (
      "primary": $primary
    ));
    
    $body-bg: #d9e0e7;
    $link-decoration: none;
    $link-color          : darken($primary, 15%);
    $link-hover-color    : darken($link-color, 15%);
    $input-bg            : tint-color($green, 95%);
    $form-check-input-bg : $input-bg;
    $form-select-bg      : $input-bg;
    $breadcrumb-active-color: darken($primary, 30%);
    // bs5.3 changed default bg colors for several elements to the $body-bg. Override back to white.
    $card-bg             : $white;
    $table-bg            : $white;
    $dropdown-bg         : $white;
    $list-group-bg       : $white;
    //$enable-dark-mode    : false;
    
    @import "variables";
    @import "variables-dark";
    @import "maps";
    @import "mixins";
    @import "root";
    
    @import "utilities";
    @import "reboot";
    @import "type";
    @import "images";
    @import "grid";
    @import "containers";
    @import "buttons";
    
}
```

and then reference it as an attribute in the HTML:

```
<body data-bs-theme="custommode">
```

[SASS demo](https://codeply.com/p/ZX9apOEEfR)

Comment: Thank you for responding. I see your demo indeed works, but this is not how I am importing bootstrap to my project, so it isn't working for me. As I mentioned above, "Which do I use and how do I use it? Where do I define my new color-mode? (I am currently using "Option B" as [shown here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/color-modes/#custom-color-modes))". In trying your solution, I added it after importing `_root.scss" but it didn't work.

Comment: Where are your custom changes.. are they in separate file? How are you importing bootstrap?

Comment: Aside from the color mode issue.. do you have a simple bootstrap customization working?

Comment: so you have them in a file named `content.scss`? .. if you have SASS customizations working then this works the exactly same way .. please update the question to show all of the relevant code and in which files .. and what customizations are currently working

Comment: Code added above. yes, essentially a `content.scss` but called `_bootstrap_custom.scss`. It isn't clear to me _where_ I should insert the code you provided. thank you again for your answers!

Comment: Again, it all just gets wrapped in the `data-bs-theme[] {}` section. I updated the example (https://www.codeply.com/p/ZX9apOEEfR) and it still works... are you importing things like "buttons" so you actually see the primary color?

Comment: I didn't try your newest solution yet because it seems awkward to me. Let's say I want to create 15 color-modes where only the primary color changes. Seems weird to import the entire bootstrap lib into each one. What am I missing? I also want all the 'normal' customizations to apply to every mode as well, not to mention bootstrap's own default 'light' mode. Sorry to sound so dumb, I'm just not getting it. (wish I knew why someone downvoted this)

Comment: That's well beyond the scope of your original question. SASS selectors work just like CSS selectors. If you don't want the other rules for every theme then simply move them out of the `data-bs-theme[] {}` section

Comment: Thank you again Carol, but it is **not** beyond the scope of the original question. I clearly said "In the end I will create multiple modes with different primary colors.".