# Override primary color when changing data-bs-theme value

Tags: themes, overriding, bootstrap-5

Using v5.3.0 bootstrap, I want to override my primary when the data attribute theme (data-bs-theme) is altered. But doesn't seem to work.

I made a _variable-theme2.scss that goes like this :

```
$theme2: #5191FF;

@include color-mode(theme2) {

  --bs-primary: #{$theme2};
  --bs-primary-rgb: #{to-rgb($theme2)};

}
```

looking at the web inspector, my 2 freshly declared CSS variables scoped on theme2 are overrided by the :root, data-bs-theme="light"

I surely have forgotten something or done something wrong.

Any hint ?

Thanks

EDIT :
I tried this and it works but obvioulsy only for the scope

```
$theme2: #5191FF;

@include color-mode(theme2) {

  .btn-primary{
    --bs-btn-bg: #{$theme2};
    --bs-border-color: #{$theme2};
    --bs-btn-hover-bg: #{lighten($theme2, 20%)};
    --bs-btn-hover-border-color: #{lighten($theme2, 20%)};
  }

}
```

Means I'll have to override every single component using the primary key.

Comment: Did you put `data-bs-theme="light"` in your html tag?

Comment: very similar to [my recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76780787/bootstrap-5-3-create-basic-color-mode) I look forward to seeing if this gets a workable answer.

Comment: @CarolSkelly yes I did.

Comment: @craigh, looks like we've all been there. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/37983

Comment: @AildeuPooley shouldn't you have put `data-bs-theme="theme2"` in your html tag?

Comment: @craigh yeah I put the light by default and changed the value via inspector to see if the override was good.